# Sum all new dynamic rows records excel sheet

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I am looking for a formula to Sum all the rows in A column, the rows count is not known as user can enter runtime. Every formula on google is taking nth row range.
[image: Excel Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used table you can use the table name references in your formula. Every time the table size increase or decrease in row numbers, the formula will adjust to the new range, given the same header name is used.

So the formula for column A (entered in cell `H10`) would look like this:

```
=SUM(Table1[[#All];[Value]])
```

`Table1`: Is the name of your table. Click on your table and go to "Design" (see picture). At the very left you have the table name, in my case "Table1".

`[#All]`: Defines what you want to look at, in this case all values.

`[Value]`: Which column (header name of the specific column) you want to evaluate.

[image]

The formula for the other looks like (cell `H11`):

```
=SUM(Table1[[#All];[Mortgage]])
```

and (for cell `H12`):

```
=SUM(Table1[[#All];[Amount]])
```

Comment: Fun to help :)!!. Don't forget to mark the post as solved if you think this solved your problem (the grey ticker below voting buttons), I would really appreciate it as it shows everyone else this is solved and give the person who answered some credit.

Answer (score 0):

There are function options with Table use that Option to add sum of that column then you'll get sum of column A when use that option!

Check this link: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/10/31/excel-sum-column/ -- check "Convert your data into Excel table to get total for your column" in this article.

it has detailed information how to do various operation with sum!

Comment: This is not for dynamic rows but predefined rows

Comment: you mentioned that count is unknown so it is dynamic row.